# Mostrar datos de varias tablas relacionadas en Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sql, orm, doctrine

Estoy empezando en el mundo de Symfony y PHP y me está surgiendo un problema.

Tengo dos tablas A y B, que están relacionadas entre ellas en una relacion OneToMany. 
En la tabla A tengo todos los datos y en la B todos lo datos mas la id_a para relacionarlos. A la hora de añadir datos por formulario funciona todo correctamente y se relacionan.

Lo que necesito conseguir es mostrar por TWIG los datos, de la tabla B principalmente, pero también añadiendo campos de la tabla A siempre y cuando la Id_a dentro de B sea la misma que la ID en A.

Hasta ahora para mostrar los datos de B, por ejemplo, los muestro de la siguiente manera:

$B_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(B::class);

$B = $B_repo->findBy([],['id'=>'DESC']);

Como debería modificar esto para que también me muestre los datos de A?

Espero haberme explicado correctamente.

Gracias

Comment: Que es exactamente lo que quieres, que se muestran todos los datos de la tabla B, y además, los datos de la tabla A que están relacionados con B?

Comment: De la tabla B todos efectivamente y de la A, algunos, como por ejemplo el Nombre, la Fecha u otros que tengo, no solamente el campo relacionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres acceder a los atributos del objeto A que está relacionado con B, esto lo debas hacer directamente en el *template*.

Primero, desde el controlador envías el objeto B tal como lo has hecho:

```html
/**
 * Método mostrar todos los objetos 
 * B y los objetos A relacionados
 * 
 * @Route("/prueba", name="pruebas")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function pruebaAction(Request $request)
{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntity();
  $objetosB = $em->getRepository(B::class)->findBy([],['id'=>'DESC']);
  
  return $this->render('prueba/prueba.html.twig', array(
      'objetosB' => $objetosB
  ));
}
```

De esta manera obtenemos todos los objetos B, y **también los objetos A relacionados**.
Esto quiere decir que al cargar los objetos A relacionados también vamos a tener acceso a sus propiedades.

Ahora, en el template **prueba.html.twig**:

```html
{% for B in objetosB %}
  {{ B.nombre }} tiene el siguiente objeto A relacionado: {{ B.a.nombre }}
{% endfor %}
```

Con la primera línea iteramos (recorremos uno a uno) los objetos B pasados desde el controlador.
Con la siguiente sintaxis: `{{ objeto.propiedad }}` podemos obtener las propiedades del objeto, incluso de los objetos relacionados, por lo que cuando ponemos:

```html
{{ B.a.nombre }}
```

Estamos accediendo al objeto A relacionado, y en concreto, la propiedad *nombre*.

Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a la [documentación de twig.](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/)

Espero que te sirva.